# Report to track all actions in SF

Tags: action, custom-reports, monitoring

How can I create a report that will help me to monitor all actions made in SF cases?
For example, I've a user that is moving cases between views, updating/editing certain fields in cases, adding case comments.

Currently, I'm creating a report using case history, filter by an edit by field, but when that user is adding a case comment to a case that doesn't belong to him I can't see it in the report.

I want to be able to track these updates, what is the easiest to do so?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to create separate reports and prepare dashboards from them

Answer (score 0):

Since not a single report can display all the actions performed on Case object. So you need to create Custom Object (Case_Tracker__c) which could be Master-Detail to Case.

You need to write trigger to store values in the object.

This object may include following attributes:

- Action Performed
- Performed By
- Performed Date
- Object Name or API Name

and others that are relevant to your use case and finally build a report on this object.